# Xamarin Forms ListView not showing highlight upon returning from another page

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I have looked all over the internet and cannot find quite the same thing I'm experiencing.

Looking for advice on how to ensure the selected item in a ListView has the selection highlight when returning from another page. It appears the ItemSelected event is not firing and although the item that is selected is correct, there is no highlight.

Unfortunately, I cannot upload any code as this is a proprietary software. I was able to figure out how to set the highlight on initial entry by using the ItemAppearing event, which is ok because the number of items will be small, under 20. However, I cannot seem to figure out an event that runs upon reentry to the page.

Any advice or thought would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you resetting the SelectedItem to null?

Comment: As @BrunoCaceiro said,  If you are push one page and then pop that page and want to Item to selected then remove  listview.SelectedItem = null; this line from your Itemselected property.

Comment: Nope, not setting the SelectedItem to null at any time. Unless it's happening automatically somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I Figured out what I was doing wrong (or maybe I didn't know at the time). Setting the ListView's SelectedItem to null was actually the answer.

I believe what was happening was when I came back to the page the SelectedItem was trying to be set back to what it already was, and I believe the system was saying "oh, it's the same thing, I'm going to ignore it". By setting the SelectedItem to null first and then assigning it, it says "Oh it's a change, I better do something".